# how do I separate a text with a list?

Tags: python, string, list, split, charactercount

this is my code however it keeps outputting the answer as one while I want it to count the characters in the sentence.

```
#-----------------------------
myList = []
characterCount = 0
#-----------------------------

Sentence = "hello world"
newSentence = Sentence.split(",")
myList.append(newSentence)
print(myList)
for character in myList:
    characterCount += 1
print (characterCount)
```

thank you for your help

Comment: If you want count of the characters in the sentence, why not use `len(Sentence)`?

Comment: `sentence.split(",")` tries to find "," and split sentence every time he finds that character. It has no ',', so it won't split it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The one line solution

```
len(list("hello world"))  # output 11
```

or...

## Quick fix to your original code

Revised code:

```
#-----------------------------
myList = []
characterCount = 0
#-----------------------------

Sentence = "hello world"
myList = list(Sentence)
print(myList)
for character in myList:
    characterCount += 1
print (characterCount)
```

Output:

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the sentence and count the characters that way:

```
#-----------------------------
myList = []
characterCount = 0
#-----------------------------

Sentence = "hello world"

for character in Sentence:
    characterCount += 1

print(characterCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you made a few mistakes: split separator should be ' ' instead of ',', no need to create a new list, and you were looping over words instead of characters.

The code should like the following:

```
myList = []
characterCount = 0
#-----------------------------

Sentence = "hello world"
newSentence = Sentence.split(" ")

for words in newSentence:
    characterCount += len(words)

print (characterCount)
```